# I want to delete the records from a parent table using child table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (A) having 200,000 records. I have created a backup table (B) from the same table (A) which contains around 100,000 records. Now I have to delete all the records which are present in table B from the parent table A.
I am using the below query:

```sql
delete from A where id in (select id from B);
```

The query which I am using is taking a lot of time, the delete is happening very slowly. Could someone please help me in reducing the time taken while deleting the records??

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you already checked this solved problem on Stack Exchange? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34864/most-efficient-way-of-bulk-deleting-rows-from-postgres

Comment: hi ,I tried to create index on the id column for both the tables but still its not working

Comment: Hi @lemon, i have also tried by dropping all other indexes , but still the query is taking time

Comment: Probably there's not much you can do to overcome this issue (nothing that I know at least).

Comment: Please show the `explain (analyze, buffers)` for the statement, or if it too slow to ever finish than at least the `explain`.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: i am using 12.7 version

Comment: The main table A is referencing another 2 tables , and having foreign key constraints for both of them

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a table with the records you want to keep, dropping the old A table, and renaming the new one back to A?

A query like:

```
Create table C
Select A.*
From A Left Outer Join B ON A.id=B.id
Where B.id is null
```

should perform well if id is indexed.

Comment: Dropping table A could be a problem if you've got a rat's nest of foreign key constraints however.